# http://harbour.space/ - What jQuery effect is this? When I zoom out the circle disappears

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js

How do I achieve this effect? I am looking to make a triangle instead of this circle. What technique should I use for animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like ScrollMagic or Scrollr. See:

- http://scrollmagic.io/
- http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

But maybe they used something else.